# Python Code for Merging Two Spreadsheets that is similar to the "Index-Match-Match" function in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have two separate spreadsheets and using pandas in order to convert them into data frames.  I am looking to extract out information from spreadsheet 2 and merge that information into spreadsheet 1.  I know how to extract the information in excel, by utilizing an "index-match-match" function, but I am having trouble figuring this out in Python since it doesn't seem to fit a merge or join method... or maybe I'm just missing the connection.

Spreadsheet 1 would look like this:
[Spreadsheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbEvX.jpg)

Spreadsheet 2 would look like this:
[Spreadsheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK49b.png)

The head of the final result would like this:

**Region   Branch     Master_Product_Name   Retrieved_#**

- North,    Fresno,       Product 1:             *5,060*
- North,    Fresno,       Product 2:             *2,429*
- North,    Sacramento,   Product 3:               *405*
- North,    Fresno,       Product 6:                *10*

What happens is the program will insert a new column and will insert the data based on indexing the column and row to get to the single data point.  So for the very first row in my example which is Fresno and Product 1... it will look in spreadsheet two across the top row until it gets to Product 1 and then down to until it finds Fresno and the insert 5,060.

Under the current scenario, having the Region column is not significant, but having the ability to retrieve based on multiple criteria is something I can envision.

Comment: Welcome to SO Matt_L. Sadly your ask is not very clear. Are you looking for help with your Python code? If so can you please include it in your question so that someone can provide pointed suggestions. Regards,

Comment: Thank you!  I am looking for python code.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We're here to help you when you have problems with your code, not to write it for you.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I apologize, if someone like to point me in the right direction to research it on my own, I gladly will.  I have been unable to figure out any documentation for a merge/join scenario that i am experiencing.  Which is merging two spreadsheets where the information is indexed, rather than in one column.

Comment: If you have the data into Pandas dataframes, you may want to start here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Thank you again Alex.  I did try looking at documentation and asking others before coming to SO.  Admittedly, I am a noob, so maybe I'm just missing the connection between the documentation and what I'm trying code.  So far as I can tell, I don't see anything where key1 is in a column and key 2 is across a row.  I do see multi-index merging, but that is based on both keys being in the same format (both columns for example).

Comment: You could use fancy indexing and then create a new series and fill it. It would be slow, however. It would probably be faster to just use a dictionary and then make a series from dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) dataframe `df2` created from `Spreadsheet 2`. Then you need `rename` column converted from rows - `Master Product Name`.

If you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by columns `Region`, `Master Product Name` and `Branch`, you have to lowercase both `Branch` columns for matching.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('s1.csv', sep=";", index_col=None)
print df1

   Region         Branch Master Product Name
0   North         FRESNO           Product 1
1   North         FRESNO           Product 2
2   North     SACRAMENTO           Product 2
3   North         FRESNO          Product 12
4   North  INLAND EMPIRE          Product 13
5   North         FRESNO           Product 4
6   North         FRESNO           Product 5
7   North      SAN DIEGO           Product 3
8   North         FRESNO           Product 3
9   North         FRESNO           Product 3
10  North    LOS ANGELES           Product 3
11  North         FRESNO           Product 6
12  North         FRESNO           Product 7
13  North         FRESNO           Product 8
14  North  SAN FRANCISCO           Product 8
15  North         FRESNO          Product 11
16  North         FRESNO           Product 9
17  South    LOS ANGELES          Product 12
18  South    LOS ANGELES           Product 3
19  North  SAN FRANCISCO           Product 1
20  North  SAN FRANCISCO           Product 2
21  North  SAN FRANCISCO          Product 12
22  North  SAN FRANCISCO          Product 13
23  North  SAN FRANCISCO           Product 4
24  North  SAN FRANCISCO           Product 5
25  South       SAN JOSE           Product 3
26  South       SAN JOSE           Product 3
```

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('s2.csv', sep=";", index_col=None)
print df2
          Branch Region Product 1 Product 2  Product 3  Product 4  Product 5  \
0         Fresno  North     5 060     2 429        675        540         10   
1     Sacramento  North     5 534     2 344        405        324        118   
2  San Francisco  North     2 924     1 167        111         89         32   
3       San Jose  North     4 039     2 019        179        143        102   
4    Los Angeles  South     4 453     2 273        302        298         -2   
5  Inland Empire  South     4 680     2 091        404        400         21   
6  Orange County  South     3 167     1 493         95         94         41   
7      San Diego  South     5 468     2 439        282        279         16   

   Product 6  
0         10  
1        117  
2         32  
3        102  
4         76  
5         41  
6         67  
7        188
```

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['Region', 'Branch'])
df2 = df2.stack()
df2 = df2.reset_index(name = 'Count')

df2 = df2.rename(columns={'level_2':'Master Product Name'})
```

```
print df2

   Region         Branch Master Product Name  Count
0   North         Fresno           Product 1  5 060
1   North         Fresno           Product 2  2 429
2   North         Fresno           Product 3    675
3   North         Fresno           Product 4    540
4   North         Fresno           Product 5     10
5   North         Fresno           Product 6     10
6   North     Sacramento           Product 1  5 534
7   North     Sacramento           Product 2  2 344
8   North     Sacramento           Product 3    405
9   North     Sacramento           Product 4    324
10  North     Sacramento           Product 5    118
11  North     Sacramento           Product 6    117
12  North  San Francisco           Product 1  2 924
13  North  San Francisco           Product 2  1 167
14  North  San Francisco           Product 3    111
15  North  San Francisco           Product 4     89
16  North  San Francisco           Product 5     32
17  North  San Francisco           Product 6     32
18  North       San Jose           Product 1  4 039
19  North       San Jose           Product 2  2 019
20  North       San Jose           Product 3    179
21  North       San Jose           Product 4    143
22  North       San Jose           Product 5    102
23  North       San Jose           Product 6    102
24  South    Los Angeles           Product 1  4 453
25  South    Los Angeles           Product 2  2 273
26  South    Los Angeles           Product 3    302
27  South    Los Angeles           Product 4    298
28  South    Los Angeles           Product 5     -2
29  South    Los Angeles           Product 6     76
30  South  Inland Empire           Product 1  4 680
31  South  Inland Empire           Product 2  2 091
32  South  Inland Empire           Product 3    404
33  South  Inland Empire           Product 4    400
34  South  Inland Empire           Product 5     21
35  South  Inland Empire           Product 6     41
36  South  Orange County           Product 1  3 167
37  South  Orange County           Product 2  1 493
38  South  Orange County           Product 3     95
39  South  Orange County           Product 4     94
40  South  Orange County           Product 5     41
41  South  Orange County           Product 6     67
42  South      San Diego           Product 1  5 468
43  South      San Diego           Product 2  2 439
44  South      San Diego           Product 3    282
45  South      San Diego           Product 4    279
46  South      San Diego           Product 5     16
47  South      San Diego           Product 6    188
```

```
#for metching by columns Branch - string to lowercase
df1['Branch'] = df1['Branch'].str.lower()
df2['Branch'] = df2['Branch'].str.lower()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Region','Master Product Name', 'Branch'])

print df

   Region         Branch Master Product Name  Count
0   North         fresno           Product 1  5 060
1   North         fresno           Product 2  2 429
2   North     sacramento           Product 2  2 344
3   North         fresno           Product 4    540
4   North         fresno           Product 5     10
5   North         fresno           Product 3    675
6   North         fresno           Product 3    675
7   North         fresno           Product 6     10
8   South    los angeles           Product 3    302
9   North  san francisco           Product 1  2 924
10  North  san francisco           Product 2  1 167
11  North  san francisco           Product 4     89
12  North  san francisco           Product 5     32
```

Comment: I was unfamiliar with the stack method and helps solve my dilemma. Thank you!  I'm still curios if there is a way to pull the data point over without manipulating the second data frame.

Comment: Maybe it is possible, I don't know. But pandas is optimized for vector working and use high optimized functions like `stack` and `merge` and this is the best practice.

Comment: @jezrael, @Matt_L the merge looks unnecessary. I think all the relevant info is contained on df2, so in fact you're looking for a `stack`, not a `merge`